# Перейти на сайт и нажать кнопку

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer

В приложении Winforms добавлена кнопка. При клике на нее должен быть осуществлен переход по url, заполнено поле и нажата кнопка.
Например, открываем google.com

```
using system.Diagnostics;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Затем уже в браузере необходимо ввести текст в строку поиска и нажать кнопку Поиск.
Есть какие-то варианты передачи этих действий во внешний браузер?
Сайт, который будет открываться, не поддерживает GET запросы.

Comment: По юзер-агенту на сайте определи, что это IE11, а затем сделай редирект с отправкой браузеру аутентификационной куки (или сессию запусти) с параметрами конкретного юзера.

Comment: Дополнил - сайт мне не пренадлежит. Моя задача только открыть ссылку на сайт в IE, ввести данные и нажать Log In.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756304/logging-into-a-website-using-c-sharp-programmatically

Comment: Вы совершенно не должны хотеть открывать браузер! Это не правильно! Работайте с сайтом напрямую, отправляйте ему запросы, которые он просит, ВСЕ сайты работают по принципу `post`/`get`/`put` и др запросов, либо при использование сокетов. Банально откройте гугл, нажмите F12 в браузере, перейдите на вкладку `Network` и начните писать в поисковой строке, увидите запросы, а при нажатие ввода вы увидите основной запрос, вот все это вам надо отправить программно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ мне необходимо выполнить авторизацию, чтобы пользователь продолжил работу в браузере. Для этого открывается браузер.

Answer (score 2):

Берем библиотеку C# для Google Chrome Браузера. 
Устанавливаем Nuget пакет:
  Install-Package MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools -Version 1.1.0
Далее пример для консольного приложения:

```
using MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.Protocol.Chrome.Page;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.Protocol.Chrome.DOM;
using Task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;

namespace MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.Sample
{
    internal class Program
    {
        const int ViewPortWidth = 1440;
        const int ViewPortHeight = 900;
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                // synchronization
                var screenshotDone = new ManualResetEventSlim();

                // STEP 1 - Run Chrome
                var chromeProcessFactory = new ChromeProcessFactory(new StubbornDirectoryCleaner());
                using (var chromeProcess = chromeProcessFactory.Create(9222, true))
                {
                    // STEP 2 - Create a debugging session
                    var sessionInfo = (await chromeProcess.GetSessionInfo()).LastOrDefault();
                    var chromeSessionFactory = new ChromeSessionFactory();
                    var chromeSession = chromeSessionFactory.Create(sessionInfo.WebSocketDebuggerUrl);

                    // STEP 3 - Send a command
                    //
                    // Here we are sending a commands to tell chrome to set the viewport size 
                    // and navigate to the specified URL
                    await chromeSession.SendAsync(new SetDeviceMetricsOverrideCommand
                    {
                        Width = ViewPortWidth,
                        Height = ViewPortHeight,
                        Scale = 1
                    });

                    var navigateResponse = await chromeSession.SendAsync(new NavigateCommand
                    {
                        Url = "http://www.google.com"
                    });
                    Console.WriteLine("NavigateResponse: " + navigateResponse.Id);

                    // STEP 4 - Register for events (in this case, "Page" domain events)
                    // send an command to tell chrome to send us all Page events
                    // but we only subscribe to certain events in this session
                    var pageEnableResult = await chromeSession.SendAsync<Protocol.Chrome.Page.EnableCommand>();
                    Console.WriteLine("PageEnable: " + pageEnableResult.Id);

                    chromeSession.Subscribe<LoadEventFiredEvent>(loadEventFired =>
                    {
                        // we cannot block in event handler, hence the task
                        Task.Run(async () =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("LoadEventFiredEvent: " + loadEventFired.Timestamp);

                            var documentNodeId = (await chromeSession.SendAsync(new GetDocumentCommand())).Result.Root.NodeId;
                            var bodyNodeId =
                                (await chromeSession.SendAsync(new QuerySelectorCommand
                                {
                                    NodeId = documentNodeId,
                                    Selector = "body"
                                })).Result.NodeId;
                            var height = (await chromeSession.SendAsync(new GetBoxModelCommand { NodeId = bodyNodeId })).Result.Model.Height;

                            await chromeSession.SendAsync(new SetDeviceMetricsOverrideCommand
                            {
                                Width = ViewPortWidth,
                                Height = height,
                                Scale = 1
                            });

                            Console.WriteLine("Taking screenshot");
                            var screenshot = await chromeSession.SendAsync(new CaptureScreenshotCommand { Format = "png" });

                            var data = Convert.FromBase64String(screenshot.Result.Data);
                            File.WriteAllBytes("output.png", data);
                            Console.WriteLine("Screenshot stored");

                            // tell the main thread we are done
                            screenshotDone.Set();
                        });
                    });

                    // wait for screenshoting thread to (start and) finish
                    screenshotDone.Wait();

                    Console.WriteLine("Exiting ..");
                }
            }).Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Библиотека [тут](https://github.com/MasterDevs/ChromeDevTools)
Работает с **DOM-объектами**, через них можно сделать всё что угодно.
Правой кнопкой мыши в Chrome на нужном сайте - посмотреть код на нужной странице и автоматизируем уже через библиотеку.

Или нужен только IE? com объекты?

```
using SHDocVw;
```

Как получить доступ к dom в IE я не знаю.

[Ещё библиотека для хрома](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BaristaLabs.ChromeDevTools.Runtime/) Их, вроде, хватает.

Answer (score 0):

А вот и не надо.

> ```
> Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
> ```

```
Process.Start("http://www.google.com/search?q=let's%20search%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD");
```

Comment: сайт, который будет открываться, не поддерживает GET запросы.
необходимо именно ввести данные и нажать кнопку.

Comment: 1. Ты спросил пор гугл. 2. Тогда бери селениум и делай всё по-другому. 3. Или вообще сам запросы посылай без браузера.

Comment: ```Например, открываем google.com``` - google указан для примера

Comment: @ Novitskiy Denis Обязательно IE? OLE объекты смотрели?  У [хрома очень много всего](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120468/control-chrome-programmatically)  Библиотеки для C# для внешнего управления браузером. + еще chrome dev...